# Flutter: Highlight Current Page Number

Tags: flutter, dart

In my bottomNavigationBar I would like to highlight the page number the user is on when scrolling through the pages of a book. This could be done by setting the backgroundcolor: _page == index ? color.blue : color.white in the ListView.builder in my bottomNavigationBar that displays a CircleAvatar for each page.

However I am unable to pass in the variable _page

I have tried the following:

Solution 1
Enable the onPageChanged in the PageView.builder of the book. It works and can pass the _page number, however I can no longer scroll through the pages (remains stuck at page 0)

Solution 2
Get the current index from the PageView.builder of the book and pass it into _page. When printed it does show the correct current page. However my Listview.builder showing the page numbers does not dynamically update and hence color does not change.

Please help me to solve this issue please.

Please see code below:

```
class BookFeeder extends StatefulWidget {
  const BookFeeder({super.key});
  static const String id = 'BookFeeder';

  @override
  State<BookFeeder> createState() => _BookFeederState();
}

class _BookFeederState extends State<BookFeeder> {
  //declare page controller

  //Hide the AppBar and bottomNavigationBar
  bool _showAppBar = false;
  bool _showBottomBar = false;
  //late PageController pageController;

  // Declare starting page
  int _page = 0;

  PageController pageController = PageController();

// TO DO: make the _activePage change when swiping the screen!!!!!
// enable the _onPageViewChange below in the PageView.Builder

  // @override
  // _onPageViewChange(int index) {
  //   setState(() {
  //     _page = index;
  //   });

  //   print("Current Page: $index");
  // }

  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
    pageController = PageController();
  }

  @override
  void dispose() {
    super.dispose();
    pageController.dispose();
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: _showAppBar
          ? AppBar(
              leadingWidth: 120,
              backgroundColor: const Color(
                (0XFF293D63),
              ),
              leading: IconButton(
                onPressed: () {
                  //print('Go Back Pressed');
                  Navigator.pop(context);
                },
                icon: SvgPicture.asset('images/button_goback_clean_svg.svg'),
              ),
              //Add to the Appbar the favourites, quizz and settings and next page
              //title: Text('First Page'),
              centerTitle: true,
              actions: [
                IconButton(
                  iconSize: 45,
                  onPressed: () {
                    Navigator.pushNamed(context, MySettings.id);
                  },
                  icon:
                      SvgPicture.asset('images/button_settings_clean_svg.svg'),
                ),
              ],
            )
          : null,

// make the navigationbar look better
      bottomNavigationBar: _showBottomBar
          ? BottomAppBar(
              height: 50,
              shape: const CircularNotchedRectangle(),
              color: Colors.white,
              elevation: 9,
              child: StreamBuilder(
                stream: FirebaseFirestore.instance
                    //Below defines which collection to get
                    .collection('Books')
                    .doc('FishingMonkey')
                    .collection('Content')
                    .snapshots(),
                builder: (context,
                    AsyncSnapshot<QuerySnapshot<Map<String, dynamic>>>
                        snapshot) {
                  if (snapshot.connectionState == ConnectionState.waiting) {
                    return const Center(child: CircularProgressIndicator());
                  }

                  return ListView.builder(
                      scrollDirection: Axis.horizontal,
                      itemCount: snapshot.data!.docs.length,
                      //itemCount: 25,
                      itemBuilder: (
                        context,
                        index,
                      ) {
                        return Padding(
                          padding: const EdgeInsets.fromLTRB(4, 4, 4, 4),
                          child: InkWell(
                            onTap: () {
                              _page = index;
                              print("Current Page: $_page");
                              pageController.animateToPage(index,
                                  duration: const Duration(milliseconds: 300),
                                  curve: Curves.easeIn);
                            },
                            child: CircleAvatar(
                                child: Text(
                                  "$index",
                                  style: TextStyle(
                                    fontSize: 12,
                                  ),
                                ),
                                radius: 10,
                                backgroundColor: Colors.blue[100]
                                // backgroundColor:
                                //     snapshot.data!.docs.length - 1 == index
                                //         ? const Color(0XFF293D63)
                                //         : 0 == index
                                //             ? const Color(0XFF293D63)
                                //             : Colors.blue[100],
                                ),
                          ),
                        );
                      });
                },
              ),
            )
          : null,

      body: GestureDetector(
        onTap: () {
          setState(() {
            _showAppBar = !_showAppBar;
            _showBottomBar = !_showBottomBar;
          });
        },
        child: ScrollConfiguration(
          behavior: ScrollConfiguration.of(context).copyWith(
            dragDevices: {
              PointerDeviceKind.touch,
              PointerDeviceKind.mouse,
            },
          ),
          child: ScrollEdgeListener(
            edge: ScrollEdge.end,
            edgeOffset: 0,
            continuous: false,
            debounce: const Duration(milliseconds: 400),
            dispatch: true,
            listener: () {
              print('end reached');
              Navigator.pop(context);
            },
            child: ScrollConfiguration(
              behavior: ScrollConfiguration.of(context).copyWith(
                dragDevices: {
                  PointerDeviceKind.touch,
                  PointerDeviceKind.mouse,
                },
              ),
              child: StreamBuilder(
                stream: FirebaseFirestore.instance
                    //Below defines which collection to get
                    .collection('Books')
                    .doc('FishingMonkey')
                    .collection('Content')
                    .snapshots(),
                builder: (context,
                    AsyncSnapshot<QuerySnapshot<Map<String, dynamic>>>
                        snapshot) {
                  if (snapshot.connectionState == ConnectionState.waiting) {
                    return const Center(child: CircularProgressIndicator());
                  }
                  //below is going to create all the different Pageviews() depending on the number of 'docs'
                  // this can be NULL (hence !) and .length provides the number
                  //onPageChanged registers the current page number. However cannot make it work with the
                  // circleavatars

                  return PageView.builder(
                      controller: pageController,
                      //onPageChanged: _onPageViewChange,
                      itemCount: snapshot.data!.docs.length,
                      itemBuilder: (context, index) {
                        //test printing
                        //print('index $index');
                        //below provides current index page
                        _page = index;

                        return BookContent(
                          //here you will request the data from 'docs' and request the whole index (starts from 0; can also do index +1)
                          //
                          snap: snapshot.data!.docs[index].data(),
                        );
                      });
                },
              ),
            ),
          ),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I use provider to store all the screen states

```dart
import 'package:flutter/gestures.dart';
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:provider/provider.dart';
import 'package:scroll_edge_listener/scroll_edge_listener.dart';

///
/// [BookFeederProvider] holds state
///
class BookFeederProvider extends ChangeNotifier {

  int _page = 0;
  bool _showAppBar = false;
  bool _showBottomBar = false;

  int get page => _page;
  bool get showAppBar => _showAppBar;
  bool get showBottomBar => _showBottomBar;

  void setPageIndex(int pageIndex) {
    _page = pageIndex;
    notifyListeners();
  }

  void setShowAppBar(bool value) {
    _showAppBar = value;
    notifyListeners();
  }

  void setShowBottomBar(bool value) {
    _showBottomBar = value;
    notifyListeners();
  }

}

void main() async {

  WidgetsFlutterBinding.ensureInitialized();

  runApp(
    /// Set up Provider
    MultiProvider(
      providers: [
        ChangeNotifierProvider<BookFeederProvider>.value(value: BookFeederProvider()),
      ],
      child: const MyApp()
    ),
  );
}

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  const MyApp({super.key});

  // This widget is the root of your application.
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      title: 'Flutter App',
      theme: ThemeData(
        colorSchemeSeed: Colors.indigo,
        useMaterial3: true,
        brightness: Brightness.light,
      ),
      darkTheme: ThemeData(
        colorSchemeSeed: Colors.blue,
        useMaterial3: true,
        brightness: Brightness.dark,
      ),
      home: const BookFeeder(),
      debugShowCheckedModeBanner: false,
    );
  }
}

class BookFeeder extends StatefulWidget {
  const BookFeeder({super.key});
  static const String id = 'BookFeeder';

  @override
  State<BookFeeder> createState() => _BookFeederState();
}

class _BookFeederState extends State<BookFeeder> {

  late BookFeederProvider _bookFeederProvider;

  PageController pageController = PageController();

  _onPageViewChange(int index) {
    _bookFeederProvider.setPageIndex(index);
  }

  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
    pageController = PageController();
  }

  @override
  void dispose() {
    super.dispose();
    pageController.dispose();
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {

    _bookFeederProvider = Provider.of<BookFeederProvider>(context);

    return Scaffold(
      appBar: _bookFeederProvider.showAppBar
          ? AppBar(
              leadingWidth: 120,
              backgroundColor: const Color(
                (0XFF293D63),
              ),
              centerTitle: true,
            )
          : null,

      bottomNavigationBar: _bookFeederProvider.showBottomBar
          ? BottomAppBar(
              height: 50,
              shape: const CircularNotchedRectangle(),
              color: Colors.white,
              elevation: 9,
              child: StreamBuilder<Object>(
                stream: null,
                builder: (context, snapshot) {
                  if (snapshot.connectionState == ConnectionState.waiting) {
                    return const Center(child: CircularProgressIndicator());
                  }
                  return ListView.builder(
                  scrollDirection: Axis.horizontal,
                  itemCount: 6,
                  itemBuilder: (context, index) {
                    return Padding(
                      padding: const EdgeInsets.fromLTRB(4, 4, 4, 4),
                      child: InkWell(
                        onTap: () {
                          _bookFeederProvider.setPageIndex(index);
                          pageController.animateToPage(index,
                            duration: const Duration(milliseconds: 300),
                            curve: Curves.easeIn
                          );
                        },
                        child: CircleAvatar(
                          child: Text("$index",
                            style: TextStyle(fontSize: 12,),
                          ),
                          radius: 10,
                          backgroundColor: _bookFeederProvider.page == index ? Colors.blue[100] : Colors.white,
                          ),
                      ),
                    );
                  });
                }
              )
            )
          : null,

      body: GestureDetector(
        onTap: () {
          _bookFeederProvider.setShowAppBar(!_bookFeederProvider.showAppBar);
          _bookFeederProvider.setShowBottomBar(!_bookFeederProvider.showBottomBar);
        },
        child: ScrollConfiguration(
          behavior: ScrollConfiguration.of(context).copyWith(
            dragDevices: {
              PointerDeviceKind.touch,
              PointerDeviceKind.mouse,
            },
          ),
          child: ScrollEdgeListener(
            edge: ScrollEdge.end,
            edgeOffset: 0,
            continuous: false,
            debounce: const Duration(milliseconds: 400),
            dispatch: true,
            listener: () {
              print('end reached');
              Navigator.pop(context);
            },
            child: ScrollConfiguration(
              behavior: ScrollConfiguration.of(context).copyWith(
                dragDevices: {
                  PointerDeviceKind.touch,
                  PointerDeviceKind.mouse,
                },
              ),
              child: StreamBuilder<Object>(
                stream: null,
                builder: (context, snapshot) {
                  
                  if (snapshot.connectionState == ConnectionState.waiting) {
                    return const Center(child: CircularProgressIndicator());
                  }
                  return PageView.builder(
                    controller: pageController,
                    onPageChanged: _onPageViewChange,
                    itemCount: 6,
                    itemBuilder: (context, index) {  
                      return ListTile(
                        title: Text('${index + 1}'),
                      );
                    }
                  );
                }
              ),
            ),
          ),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: thank you so much for taking the time to have a look. I tested your code and works as a charm, however unfortunately not when using it together with the Firebase setup. I am afraid the problem must be with my Firebase setup (perhaps using StreamBuilder). If you have any other recommendations, then that would be much appreciated. Thanks.

Comment: I have already updated my answer. Please check

Comment: Wow, amazing! It works, I can finally scroll through the pages again. However, it unfortunately still has a minor bug. If you scroll through the pages, it works fine. However, if you click the screen to see at which page you are (have the BottomAppBar pop-up), it automatically goes back to page 0. Same as your scroll through the pages with BottomAppBar visible to check page numbers, once you click to have the BottomAppBar disappear, it automatically shows page 0 again. I dare to ask, any good solution for this issue? Thanks again for putting so much effort in this and helping me out.

Comment: Yes, since we call setState when we tap on the screen, and it caused the screen to rebuild itself. That's why it move to page 0.

Comment: Is there a way we can pass in the current page when it rebuilds itself so it will not go back to page 0 but stays at the current page the user is at? Thanks

Comment: Yes, there are many ways we can do that. I have updated my answer, and I implement it using provider package.

Comment: Thanks for your help. I already had the provider package in my app, hence easy to implement. However, when using above code in my app, when trying to swipe through pages it keeps again being stuck at page 0. It does not allow me to scroll through the pages anymore unfortunately.